# Trying to display an arraylist<string> on a widget listview

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, widget

So here i am loading my array from a sharedpreferences file then making an adapter and trying to set it to my widgetlistview list.  I don't understand how i use the adapter i made (ListAdapter) considering setRemoteAdapter doesn't receive the adapter like it does in the main app activity.  I'm fairly new to android so i'm sure i missed something obvious can anyone help me out?

```
sharedprefs = context.getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
Index = sharedprefs.getInt("index", -1);

for (int IndexNum = 0; IndexNum < Index; IndexNum++){
    LoadList(IndexNum);
}

ArrayAdapter<String> ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context,R.layout.app_list_item, R.id.editdoublelistview_content,NicknamesW);
final RemoteViews v = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget);
v.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.WidgetListView,svcIntent);
```

Comment: have you set the appwidget provider xml?

Comment: yes, i have figured out more about this problem.  you need to use a class that implements RemoteViewsFactory to make the array adapter.  As far as i've read you cannot use a regular ArrayAdapter with a listview on a widget.  Just for clarity this is how i set it in the manifest.

<meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/my_widget_provider"/>

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget/src/com/commonsware/android/appwidget/lorem/LoremViewsFactory.java

here is the line of code i'm stuck on, everything else i've been able to adapt.

extras.putString(WidgetProvider.EXTRA_WORD, items[position]);

I don't know what to replace WidgetProvider.EXTRA_WORD with.

Trying to put it the same but replacing the items array with my own array does not work.  Part of the problem is i don't understand the the previous line "Bundle extras = new Bundle(); as i've never used Bundle before

Comment: For now i've commented out those 2 lines and i'm going to see what happens without them... it almost seems to me that this is to add a prefix to the array item but that is just a guess if anyone can confirm or correct me that would be appreciated, for now i'm going to code on and see what happens

Comment: the listview worked with those two lines commented out

Answer (score 0):

I used the example from the github link i posted using remoteviewsservice and .remoteviewsfactory and got it working